# How does Console in Chrome Developer Tool get implemented?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, eval

How does Console in Chrome Developer Tool get implemented?

Does it get implemented by calling `eval()` for every code snippet that has been passed in?

Comment: Can you explain some more what you mean? I don't understand

Comment: @JonasGiuro I just curious about how to implement a JavaScript interpreter like Console in Chrome.

Comment: It's open-source, you can read the code yourself: https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend. It's similar to what happens in `eval`, yes, but it's in a remote environment.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks a lot. Can you help to point out which source files are related?

Comment: [this](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/master/front_end/console/ConsolePrompt.js#L163) looks promising (although I didn't look at any other file)

Answer (score 1):

When Chrome's Javascript interpreter is compiling JS code to machine code, it converts console.log to the appropriate internal API.

Comment: actually, I am asking how does that interpreter work.

Comment: Then you should have asked that instead. https://developers.google.com/v8/